# How to enable third button cheat in final fight Mame?

Tags: mame, final-fight

In Mame we have a third button that simulates pressing punch and jump at the same time

[image]

However, it doesn't work at all. I mean I press Joy 1 Button 2 and it doesn't work. Perhaps because it's a cheat. Should I do something to the machine to enable it?

Also I put nothing for P1 button 1 that's because I need autofire.

[image]

This is the content of ffight.cfg

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- This file is autogenerated; comments and unknown tags will be stripped -->
<mameconfig version="10">
    <system name="ffight">
        <counters>
            <coins index="0" number="7" />
        </counters>
        <input>
            <port tag=":IN1" type="P1_JOYSTICK_RIGHT" mask="1" defvalue="1">
                <newseq type="standard">
                    JOYCODE_1_HATSWITCHR
                </newseq>
            </port>
            <port tag=":IN1" type="P1_JOYSTICK_LEFT" mask="2" defvalue="2">
                <newseq type="standard">
                    JOYCODE_1_HATSWITCHL
                </newseq>
            </port>
            <port tag=":IN1" type="P1_JOYSTICK_DOWN" mask="4" defvalue="4">
                <newseq type="standard">
                    JOYCODE_1_HATSWITCHD
                </newseq>
            </port>
            <port tag=":IN1" type="P1_JOYSTICK_UP" mask="8" defvalue="8">
                <newseq type="standard">
                    JOYCODE_1_HATSWITCHU
                </newseq>
            </port>
            <port tag=":IN1" type="P1_BUTTON1" mask="16" defvalue="16">
                <newseq type="standard">
                    NONE
                </newseq>
            </port>
            <port tag=":IN1" type="P1_BUTTON2" mask="32" defvalue="32">
                <newseq type="standard">
                    JOYCODE_1_BUTTON2
                </newseq>
            </port>
            <port tag=":IN1" type="P1_BUTTON3" mask="64" defvalue="64">
                <newseq type="standard">
                    JOYCODE_1_BUTTON3
                </newseq>
            </port>
        </input>
    </system>
</mameconfig>
```

I do not see anything that enables that third button either

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to https://kb.speeddemosarchive.com/Final_Fight/Basics

> A short note on button 3. Anyone who has played Final Fight in mame
> may have taken notice that button 3 can be bound, and appears to do
> nothing. This seems to be a leftover development button, and it still
> has one function. Specifically, pressing button 3 when being grabbed
> (primarily by Andores or Abigail), will result in your character
> falling out of the grab. No official documentation contains any
> references to button 3, it is not an available button on any official
> cabinet, does not show up in the input check, and it is not included
> in any port of the game, so use of button 3 is regarded as a cheat by
> SDA standards.